# What's the difference between {children} and declaring children components expliciltly inside Provider in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newbie in React world and recently I read about Context in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Here, the example goes like

```
const ContextProvider = () => (
  <Provider.Provider value={...}>
     <ConsumerComponentA />
     <ConsumerComponentB />...
   </Provider.Provider>
);
```

But, when reading the code of a friend of mine, his code goes like this:

```
const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider.Provider value={...}>
     {children}
   </Provider.Provider>
);
```

As stated [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment), the second is a better choice to go if the `children`s are unknown ahead of time. Moreover, in this [article](https://kattyacuevas.medium.com/fixing-re-renders-when-using-context-in-react-a6ac11dee0d4) the author mentions that using both approachs has different results in rendering, but doesn't go further deep in details. So, my real questios is, is there a difference in behaviour and rendering between those ways of writting Providers' children?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

First approach

You have mentioned upfront that only ComponentA and ComponentB can read the data from your context . This becomes an issue when another component `ComponentC` wanted to read your context value. This is not `flexible` .

```
const ContextProvider = () => (
  <YourContext.Provider value={...}>
     <ComponentA />
     <ComponentB />
   </YourContext.Provider>
);
```

Second Approach - **recommended**

Having the `children` prop will provide you more flexibility because now your context is not aware about the components which is going to consume its value .

```
const ContextProvider = ({children}) => (
  <YourContext.Provider value={...}>
    {children}
   </YourContext.Provider>
);
```

You can wrap it on any component,

```
<ContextProvider>
  // you can use whatever component you want here 
</ContextProvider>
```

Comment: So, the second one is a better choice than the first one if the project will grow?